# Sightly - Show the header tag only if there is a header

Tags: sightly

Using HTL (Sightly) I want to display

```
<h2 data-sly-text="${model.heading}"></h2>
```

But only if the `${model.heading}` is not empty, otherwise nothing, not even the `h2` tag.

I tried the following solution, but it didn't work:

```
<sly data-sly-test="${model.heading}"><h2 data-sly-text="${model.heading}"></h2></sly>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just write it as:

```
<h2 data-sly-test="${model.heading}" data-sly-text="${model.heading}">Heading placeholder</h2>
```

The snippet you posted should have worked too, since you did not mention what was not working I can suggest:

- checking the `model` variable is properly defined and initialised
- checking the `heading` property is properly exposed (either directly or via a `getHeading` method)

Comment: Thanks, but you're right. My solution works too. :-)